# Total-boundedness is a generalization of compactness?

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble understanding wikipedia about tatally bounded spaces :

> total-boundedness is a generalization of compactness for circumstances
> in which a set is not necessarily closed

Could any one provide some details on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I find the sentence strange, but I think it means:

1. Every compact metric space is totally bounded.
2. There are subspaces of metric spaces that are totally bounded but not closed (and therefore, not even compact). For example, $]0,1[$ is totally bounded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the usual distance.

Answer (score 4):

For any $\epsilon>0$ the compact metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ can be covered by finitely many $\epsilon$-balls — i.e., it is totally bounded. That property can be useful even when the metric space is not compact: for instance, it implies that every sequence in the space has a Cauchy subsequence. But it is strictly weaker than compactness, because that Cauchy sequence need not converge. The subspace $(0,1)$ of $\Bbb R$ with its usual metric is an example of a totally bounded space that is not compact; $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, again with the usual metric, is another.

The fact that total boundedness is a strictly weaker property than compactness makes it a generalization of compactness (in metric spaces): every compact metric space is totally bounded, but not every totally bounded metric space is compact. The specific aspect of compactness that it generalizes to a wider class of spaces is described in the next sentence in the Wikipedia article:

> A totally bounded set can be covered by finitely many subsets of every fixed "size" (where the meaning of "size" depends on the structure of the ambient space.)

Answer (score 2):

The connection between total boundedness and compactness is a somewhat subtle one, but it may be summed up in the following theorem:

A subset of a *complete* metric space is compact if and only if it is closed *and* totally bounded.

Another way to remember this, is by saying that in a complete metric space, the relatively compact subsets and the totally bounded subsets are presicely the same. A relatively compact set is set whose closure is compact.

To call total boundedness a generlization of compactness might be something of a stretch, but in a complete metric space, a totally bounded subset is as close as one gets to a compact subset without requiring closure.

Answer (score 2):

Compactness is a purely topological notion, defined in terms of open covers.

Totally bounded and completeness are metric notions (or rather uniform space notions; these can be defined in any [uniform space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) including all metric ones. A uniformity induced a topology (similar to how metrics do) and it turns out very nicely that these two purely non-topological but uniform notions combined are exactly the compactness of the uniform topology.

In that sense it's more correct to say that compelete boundedness is compactness minus the completeness (and in a complete space metric space, closed is equivalent to complete ).